# Bi publisher - querying custom user attributes

Tags: oracle, publisher, bi-publisher

How to use custom user attributes on BI PUBLESHER reports?
xdo_user_name and other systematic user attributes are being displayed after a report is being processed by data model

Data model consists of: select :xdo_address as address from dual;
After I am expecting to have an address of a user, which is set in user attributes section.
But there is an empty space instead in report.
I searched through documentation but there are only examples of using :xdo_user_name and etc.

Comment: How do you expect to have an address of a user?Are you use any parameter in your data model?

Comment: @Anastasis I have set their address in security realms section in the admin page. There is attributes table in that section